# Why is n not mentioned on the left in binomial probability?

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, likelihood

How do I read the left hand side of the equation

[image: Binomial Probability Equation]

and why is $n$ not mentioned on the left?

The source is [here.](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_78bc47ab5c6bac01bd4e79e207f0bb15_2.1-Likelihoods.pdf?Expires=1640736000&Signature=T8lLWAPy-SHo3WGngpY0yVFt7ZfeGC5oNRdm35Lf9jQTEwXV%7ETFCKzowjzuyOMYeqiru0gl%7E4L2uHRJMAB7TXWsY0cR34AsCu2c6a4AAeCJWPRTij9La7IKd0xbgNqnjyW8qn9jMiQzk-A6U4q33nUNm9j%7ETeDZ7CU622zCblZ8_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A)
Referenced from [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/statistical-inferences/supplement/z65kC/assignment-2-1-likelihoods)

Comment: If you are rigorous, yes, $n$ should be a parameter of de probability function. However, it is not uncommon to see it left out and taken as "given".

Comment: The notation also just seems wrong. It should really be $P(x; \theta, n)$

Comment: I don't believe I have ever, in more years than I care to remember, seen a probability distribution written that way.  The first link is to an article titled "Likelihood", and, so far as it goes, the left-hand side is an ordinary expression for the likelihood function of $\theta$ given the observed data $x$ and, implicitly, $n$.   Typically a probability would be written $p(x|\theta,n)$ or $p(x;\theta, n$), although as @GuilhermeMarthe notes, often the $n$ is left out and taken as given.

Comment: A binomial distribution does have two parameters $n$ and $\theta.$ Almost always $n$ is known from the start and does not change during a discussion. Usually, the discussion is to find a binomial probability such as $P(X  = 3)$ when $\theta$ is also known. Or to estimate $\theta$ for observed x and known $n.$ // Rarely, $x$ and  $\theta$ are known and the task is to estimate $n,$ but this is a much harder problem, rarely seen in beginning texts.